# How to read localized image with imageWithContentsOfFile

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, cocoa-touch, localization

this is my first question here :-)

I have an image icon_new.png which is localized for 3 languages. I need to load it in run time using something like this:

```
NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"icon_new.png"];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Problem with above is that it works for non-localized images, but for localized ones, their real path is actually appended with en.lproj, zh-Hans.lproj or other folder names depending on languages included in localization.

Now I could check what's current locale and append path accordingly:

```
// This path would work for image that's localized - for English version of it.
NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"en.lproj/icon_new.png"];
```

However I wonder if there's automatic way to do this? Just like app loads entire UI .xib file from proper locale path, so basically I would just specify image name rather than it's full path, and get proper localized version.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NSBundle`'s `-pathForResource:ofType:`, which searches the main directory first, and if it fails to find the resource there, checks the appropriate localization directories.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"icon_new" ofType:@"png"];
```

Comment: I had to add the file to Xcode before, because otherwise the pathForResource method returned nil.